# Subdivide a list in Haskell? (Without importing Data.List.Split)

Tags: haskell

I'm working on an assignment and I have to create a function that should work like this:
`[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9] 3 ->[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]` the problem is that I'm not sure if I am allowed to import libraries to complete the assignment. Can anyone help me figure out a way to do this without using `Import Data.List.Split`?

I'm fairly new to Haskell so I don't even know where I should start.

Comment: With explicit recursion. Try to come up with a base case, and a recursive case. Try to split the problem in smaller parts first. For example how would you split a list in two lists with the first list containing `3` elements, and the other list the remaining ones?

Comment: The alternative to explicit recursion is a fold (essentially any recursive list function can be implemented as a fold - I don't know if that's strictly true but certainly the vast majority can), but that likely doesn't offer any real improvement over explicit recursion here.

Comment: I've been able to make this: `subLists :: Int -> [Int] -> [[Int]]
                                              subLists 0 _ = []
                                              subLists _ [] = []
                                             subLists n l = take n l : subLists (n) (drop n l)`  It works but is there a better way to implement it?

Comment: @Ramux05: you can combine `take` and `drop`, and thus save some cycles, but this is indeed correct :)

Answer (score 2):

Usually when you do not how to start. It pays off to try to find smaller subproblems that can help you solve the larger problem.

One of those subproblems might be given a list and an integer *n*, to split the list in two sublists, where the first sublist takes the first *n* items, and the second list is the list of the remaining elements. Something like:

```
splitAt :: Int -> [a] -> ([a], [a])
splitAt n xs = …
```

Furthermore using explicit recursion is a good idea when you want to reason about the algorithm. [@RobinZigmond](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58363681/subdivide-a-list-in-haskell-without-importing-data-list-split#comment103078404_58363681) is correct if he says that a lot of list processing can be done with fold functions. But I think for now it might be better to solve the problem with explicit recursion.

A lot of list processing has the empty list as base-case, and the non-empty list as a recursive case. We thus can implement something along the lines of:

```
splitN :: Int -> [a] -> [[a]]
splitN _ [] = …
splitN n xs = …
```

Here the second line is a recursive case, and we thus implement `splitN` in terms of itself. I here have given a "skeleton" of how you can implement it. I leave it as an exercise to fill in the missing items (`…`).